# Atmega48PA-AU фьюзы

Tags: avr, atmega

Подскажите, пожалуйста, фьюзы для Atmega48PA-AU - мне нужно, чтобы МК работал от внешнего кварца 16 МГц, в остальном все по стандарту. Я уже "окирпичил" третий чип, осталось всего 2. Не хочу больше рисковать. Фиг знает, в чем дело, но вот с DIP-контроллерами все получается, а тут, в варианте с TQFP-корпусом какая-то засада...

Answer (score 1):

Короче, сам выяснил. Голый камень, скорее всего, будет работать от внутренней RC-цепочки, там около 1 МГц (судя по спец-программе, которую я сделал для проверки). Просто так МК прошиваться не будет, тут необходимо установить джампер J3 на программаторе, чтобы он работал в медленном режиме. Все фьюзы должны остаться по умолчанию, для работы с кварцем 16МГц нужно выставить 2 - это SKSEL3 и SUT0. Все остальное не трогаем, особенно всякие SPIEN и т. д. Если контроллер не завелся - отпаяйте конденсаторы. Если с ними нет ошибки схемотехники, они могут быть тупо перегреты при пайке. Еще заметил такую интересную штуку:  у микроконтроллеров в TQFP-корпусе даже без этих кондеров почему-то синусоида на XTAL-пинах какая-то особенно красивая, прям ровненькая, а не изогнутыми зубами, как на МК в DIP корпусах.